# Copy and Paste multiple cells with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, worksheet-function

I'm trying to automate a macro in an Excel Worksheet. I have a big table on the first worksheet with a variable number of rows, and I need to create a number of "plates" (group of 5 rows with certain data) for each row of the main worksheet (posted in the attached image). The plates need to be displayed as in the screenshot in order to be exported in a .pdf file (2 on the same level until the last one)

This is the code I came up to using macro recording and other macro found around and already working for me (pdf printing):

```
Sheets("Summary").Select
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
first_row = "A2"
sec_row = "F2"
For i = 1 To lastRow

Sheets("Foglio1").Select
Range("S3:V7").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("first_row:first_row+4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("sec_row:sec_row+4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

i = i + 2
Next
```

After this I have a code part where I export the selected area as pdf (easy and is working).

[image: Second worksheet where all the plates are displayed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your summary sheet is like this

[image: SUmmary Table]

then try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePDF()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsPDF As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, ar(1 To 5, 1 To 1), rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Integer, k As Integer
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Summary")
    Set wsPDF = wb.Sheets("Foglio1")
    'wsPDF.Cells.Clear

    ' fixed
    ar(1, 1) = "Factory s.r.l."
    ar(2, 1) = "Ph. +39 0000 00000"
    ar(3, 1) = "Web www.website.net"
   
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    r = 2 ' start row
    c = 1 ' column A
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        ar(4, 1) = "JOB " & ws.Cells(i, "A")
        ar(5, 1) = "ORDER " & ws.Cells(i, "B")
       
        ' fill plate
        Set rng = wsPDF.Cells(r, c).Resize(5, 1)
        rng.Value2 = ar
       
        ' merge cells
        For k = 1 To 5
            With rng.Cells(k, 1).Resize(1, 4)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        Next
        
        ' move to next plate
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            c = 6 ' column F
        Else
            c = 1 ' column A
            r = r + 6
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and in the way i wanted, i need to adapt something but overall is just perfect, i think i can handle the things i wanna change. I don't know how to thank you, you made my day.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are a number of "I wish this would work"-type parts of your code at present, and probably more questions than answers right now.

It seems like your output sheet "Foglio1" is currently formatted to accept a "plate" in six locations. If your intent is that these six should be from *different* rows of the main sheet "Summary", that's a little more complicated than putting six copies of each row up for printing.

With all the switching back and forth between sheets, it's worth working with some  `Range` and `Worksheet` variables to keep the screen from getting too busy.

There are a number of activities to separate out:

- get "plate" information from main sheet
- format appropriately
- update summary sheet
- output to pdf if the time is right

So my overall scheme would look like:

```
' set up plate locations in output sheet Array("A2","F2","A8",...)
' ---- set up range of records to scan (ScanRange) (only column A, other data by .Offset)
For Each ACell in ScanRange
    ' ---- get data from this record e.g.
    phone = ACell.Offset(0,5).Text
    ' ---- fill next plate (Range) in output sheet e.g.
    whichPlate = whichPlate + 1 ' & cycle
    Set plate = Range(plates(whichPlate))
    plate.Offset(1,0).Value = "Ph. " & phone 'etc.
    ' ---- send to pdf if appropriate
    ' ---- clean up output sheet if needed
Next ACell

' ---- send last batch to pdf
```

Comment: I really appreciate your honest reply. I have the code concept in my mind but I lack vba knowledge at the moment. I will try to follow your tip and improve my code skills. My last goal is to create a single plate from every row generated in the main worksheet (in the same order, I think that can decrease the overall complexity). 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem; you can always ask more questions as you develop the process. If you feel this is an acceptable answer, feel free to accept it with the checkmark. And if you ask another question with no general response, you can notify me by responding here too.